# Removing SceneKit emission material?

Tags: scenekit

In an effort to highlight hit items in my scene, I'm doing something like this:

```
func
highlight(note inNote: Int, highlight inHighlight: Bool)
{
    let scene = self.scene as! MainEditorScene
    let node = scene.noteNodes[inNote]
    let geom = node.geometry!

    if inHighlight
    {
        geom.firstMaterial?.emission.contents = NSColor(calibratedRed: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.3)
    }
    else
    {
        geom.firstMaterial?.emission.contents = nil
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the objects turn white but never back to their original color. Can I not remove the emission contents like this? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Make it transparent:

`geom.firstMaterial?.emission.contents = UIColor.clear`

Instead of:

`geom.firstMaterial?.emission.contents = nil`

Answer (score 0):

in SceneKit a black color, i.e.`(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`, is often the default value for "nothing" (that is a contribution of `0` in the lighting equation)

```
geom.firstMaterial?.emission.contents = NSColor.black
```